# flexigrid examples returning data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, flexigrid

I'm sure it can be done, I just need to see some examples. I want to use flexigrid to show massive sets of data stored in mysql. I am proficient in php, but new to jquery and json.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide a good example? I need to see how to return data back to the flexigrid json.

Thank you

[Great Tutorial on this topic](http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/)

Comment: Hi Jason, do you need a sample of php code that generates the JSON code? I use flexigrid in a number of projects, I am sure I have something that I could provide

Comment: silly question, are you including jquery?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // You may specify partial version numbers, such as "1" or "1.3",
  //  with the same result. Doing so will automatically load the 
  //  latest version matching that partial revision pattern 
  //  (e.g. 1.3 would load 1.3.2 today and 1 would load 1.4.2).
  google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
 google.load("jqueryui", "1");

  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // Place init code here instead of $(document).ready()
  });
  
</script>

Comment: Also, is the div id equal to flex1?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. flexgrid is showing. it's just not producing any content. I am including Jquery 1.4.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the partial code for returning your database results, you would call you page with the flexigrid jquery code

```
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
         $data['rows'][] = array(
                                  'id' => $row['pf_id'],
                                  'cell' => array(
                                               $row['cat_code'], 
                                               $row['cat_title'], 
                                               $row['cat_link'] = "<a href=\"catagory_edit.php?cat_id=".$row['cat_id']."\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"catagory_to_family_association.php?cat_id=".$row['cat_id']."\">Associate Familys</a> | <a href=\"category_child_order.php?cat_id=".$row['cat_id']."\">Order Children</a>")); }
echo json_encode($data);
```

call the page with the flexigrid jquery code

```
$("#flex1").flexigrid({
            url: 'category_main_json.php',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        colModel : [
                            {display: 'Code', name : 'cat_code', width : 70, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                            {display: 'Name', name : 'cat_title', width : 550, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                            {display: 'Action', name : 'cat_link', width : 205, sortable : true, align: 'left'},
                            ],
                        buttons : [
                            {name: 'Add New Category', bclass: 'add', onpress : test},
                            {separator: true}
                            ],
                        searchitems : [
                            {display: 'Code', name : 'cat_code'},
                            {display: 'Name', name : 'cat_title', isdefault: true}
                            ],
                        sortname: "cat_code",
                        sortorder: "asc",
                        usepager: true,
                        useRp: true,
                        rp: 50,
                        showTableToggleBtn: false,
                        resizable: false,
                        width: 880,
                        height: 450,
                        singleSelect: true,
                        showTableToggleBtn: false

                    }
                );
```

Comment: so basically you create the array you want in php (for each table data) and then json encode it? seems pretty easy, thanks. let's see if i can get it to work now. :)

Comment: Yep... depending on what version you have of PHP you may need the json encode script.

Comment: Check out the revision above.I have a couple problems, but I can see how helpful this will be in the future.

Comment: Solved it, was missing some pieces returned in the json.

Comment: Hey JoeyH ? Are you there, I want to confirm some matter about flexgrid.  Waiting...Please